# Print a list backwards

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code which i want to print this list backwards but it didn't work.

It prints `[2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10, 10]`

```
def printBackwards (list) :
  i = len(list) 
  while (i > 0):
  list.append(list[i-1])
   i = i +1
  print(list)
  return

myslist = [2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10]
printBackwards(myslist)
```

What i want is to print it `[10 , 8 , 6 , 4 , 2]` How can this be done ?

EDIT: I want use my code not `[::-1]` or `reverse()` or something from other post WHICH  I have seen . so its not duplicate . I dont want just work from what ever code however I want to edit my code to work. Thanks.

Comment: `i=i-1` not `i=i+1` I suppose

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: There is no way the code you provided prints `[2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10, 10]`. You have an infinite loop  and your indentation is incorrect. Also the `return` does nothing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def printBackwards(x) :
    i = len(x) 
    new_x = []
    while (i > 0):
        new_x.append(x[i-1])
        i -= 1
    print(new_x)

myslist = [2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10]
printBackwards(myslist)
```

Use `i-=1` to decrement the index and perhaps you might want to create a new variable to store the result.

Alternatively, you can also append you result to the existing list and print out the second part after the loop.

```
def printBackwards(x) :
    i = len(x)
    n = i
    while (i > 0):
        x.append(x[i-1])
        i -= 1
    print(x[n:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def printBackwards(list_1): 
    list_2 = [] 
    i = len(list_1)  
    while (i > 0): 
        list_2.append(list_1[i-1]) 
        i = i -1 
    return list_2 


myslist = [2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10] 
print(printBackwards(myslist))
```

Create a local list and append to that list.

Input and output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create an local list in the reverse order using `insert`

```
def print_backwards(in_list):
    out = []
    for x in in_list:
        out.insert(0, x)
    print(out)
```